# XML and JSON feeds in javascript. Access allowed, only sometimes

Tags: javascript, xml, json

Something weird i've noticed with accessing XML and JSON feeds using javascirpt is that access is often denied (for security reasons I guess...).

Chrome says: **XMLHttpRequest cannot load graph.facebook.com/100001263589003/feed. Origin fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

As you can see in this script: http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/RvQVX/2/

**graph.facebook.com/100001263589003/feed?callback=?** will work

and

**graph.facebook.com/100001263589003/feed** will not work

Why ? and how can I figure it out, that an argument such as callback for facebook is provided by the API ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why ?

Your JS library is probably switching to use JSON-P (cross domain hack that requires the co-operation of the target site) instead of XMLHttpRequest (subject to the same origin policy) when you include `callback=?` in the URI.

> and how can I figure it out, that an argument such as callback for facebook is provided by the API ?

Read the documentation for the API

Comment: I see. That would mean that not any json feed is readable using javascript ? By the way, what about xml feeds ? i've experienced same issues with that format. It seems that this API is the solution for XML: http://code.google.com/apis/feed/

Comment: Any JSON or XML feed is readable with JS. The restriction is on requesting data from a different origin. JSON-P gets around that by having the data provider wrap the data in a script.

Comment: I'm not going to dig too closely into it right now, but it looks like just another third party server side JSON-P wrapping service. You can do the same sort of thing with Yahoo! Pipes or YQL.